# SQL Server grouping column value

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have am having a problem grouping the column of my table

```
Private Sub BindRepeater()
    Dim cn As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("db").ConnectionString
    Using cs As New SqlConnection(cn)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * from tbl_in_record GROUP BY in_pc_no", cs)
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim dt As New DataTable()
                sda.Fill(dt)
                rptTableIn.DataSource = dt
                rptTableIn.DataBind()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

It displays this error

> Column 'tbl_in_record.in_no' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

My table looks like this

```
  in_id      in_pc_no
```

---

```
  1   abc-def-ghi1-01  
  2   abc-def-ghi1-01  
  3   abc-def-ghi1-01  
 12   abc-def-ghi1-01  
 13   abc-def-ghi1-01  
 14   abc-def-ghi1-01  
 15   abc-def-ghi1-01
```

Comment: What would you like the output to look like?

Comment: just showing 2 rows
101-33X-7104-01 and
101-33X-7014-02 and other corresponding column value

Comment: Then replace the `*` with `in_pc_no` only. `*` means you are selecting `in_id` also which means you cannot group `in_pc_no` without having to group `in_id` also unless you are summarizing a field which in your case is you're not summarizing an ID.

Comment: ah thank you so much ..didn't know that * cannot be used in grouping

Comment: You can still use `*`. But you will have to add all the fields in the table you are selecting with `*` in your `Group By` statement.

Comment: Currently your group by doesn't make sense as you are not using any aggregate method in select so if you want distinct values for `in_pc_no` you better of using `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you would use either:

```
SELECT DISTINCT in_pc_no FROM tbl_in_record;
```

or

```
SELECT in_pc_no FROM tbl_in_record GROUP BY in_pc_no;
```

Any other fields that are included need to have some aggregation function, e.g.

```
SELECT in_pc_no, n = Count(in_id) FROM tbl_in_record GROUP BY in_pc_no;
```